# messageComposeViewController Error in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

The following code worked in Swift 1.2. Now, I get an error:

> "Value of type MessageComposeResult has no member 'value'"

```
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch (result.value) {
    case MessageComposeResultCancelled.value:
        print("Message was cancelled")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResultFailed.value:
        print("Message failed")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResultSent.value:
        print("Message was sent")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

What member of the result am I supposed to check in order to find the status of the message in Swift 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Swift 2, `value` does not exist in `result`.

Use `result.rawValue`, instead.

Answer (score 3):

**use rawValue instead of value**

```
   switch result.rawValue {
    case MessageComposeResult.Cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Message was cancelled")
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    case MessageComposeResult.Failed.rawValue:
        print("Message failed")
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    case MessageComposeResult.Sent.rawValue:
        print("Message was sent")
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

    default:
        break
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what changed please ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To improve it you could add an explanation of what you've changed, and why those changes solve the OP's issue.